# Parse, run Push Job with Where clause doesn't work

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push, where-clause

I use Parse.com and I am trying to run a Job Script which should Push only specific installations.

I use a **Where** clause in JSON data... But nothing change, all devices are pushed...

Below my Cloud code with explicit where clause :

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('objectId', "nonono");

    Parse.Push.send({
      channels: [ "MyDistrict" ],
      data: {
        "where": query, 
        "alert": "Votre quartier à besoin de vous !",
        "action": "1",
        "title": "Cherche héros"
      }
    }, { 
        success: function() { 
            status.success("Great, "+pushList.length+" users was just push ! DEBUG : "+JSON.stringify(query));
    }, error: function(err) { 
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
      }
    });
```

Is this the right way ?

I have only one row in my Installation Table which have a field "objectId" equal to "lLWDVlQUYW"...

Comment: Post that as answer, instead of `EDIT Resolved`. It will be useful for others. Also, don't forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move out "where" of the "data" array. Like "channels".

**WARNING !**

You can't use both "channels" and "where" ! So you just have to include channels in your "where" query like that :

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('objectId', "nonono");
query.equalTo('channels',"MyDistrict");


Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: {
    "alert": "Votre quartier à besoin de vous !",
    "action": "1",
    "title": "Cherche héros"
  }
}, { 
    success: function() { 
        status.success("Great, "+pushList.length+" users was just push !");
}, error: function(err) { 
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong. > "+JSON.stringify(err));
  }
});
```

Thats work for me :)